# Disable Objective C ARC using XCodeConfig settings

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, llvm

It is easy to turn off ARC in XCode using the `Build Phases` tricks, but is it possible to specify using `XCodeConfig`?

Seems to me that using XCodeConfig approach (if possible) is more flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARC is implicitly off.

You *could* add this to your xcconfig:

`CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = NO`

*but* you would still have the problem where the project/target/file local build settings override that behavior. You should just be able to grep your Xcode projects for `CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC` and `objc-arc` to find where it is actually enabled.

Comment: I only want to turn off for a particular file, not globally, is it possible in XCodeConfig?

Comment: @Yoga sorry, no means that i know of to do that on a per-file basis. static libraries are an option, depending on the set of files you have  to configure.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on or off ARC in your .xcconfig files by using the option:

```
CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = NO
```

Comment: I only want to turn off for a particular file, not globally, is it possible in XCodeConfig?

Comment: @Ryan do you get the answer?

Comment: As mentioned in justin's answer below, you can't do this per file. This does not really make sense as objects typically move between files and it would be bad to use ARC to track their lifetime in some files and not others.